# "rethinkdb.errors.ReqlServerCompileError: Expected 2 arguments but found 1 in:" when trying to .update() with Python rethink

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm working with RethinkDB using the Python module and right now I'm trying to update a model with this statement:

```
results = rethink.table(model + "s").filter(id=results["id"]).update(data).run(g.rdb_conn)
```

`model` is something being defined earlier in the function, in this case it's `quote` and `data` is a dict of JSON data:

```
{
    "channelId": "paradigmshift3d",
    "quoteId": "1",
    "quote": "Testing 123",
    "userId": "123",
    "messageId": "456"
}
```

According to the [RethinkDB API reference](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/update/) that statement I'm using *should* work, but it's not. Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/nate/CactusAPI/views.py", line 309, in chan_quote
    fields=fields
  File "/home/nate/CactusAPI/helpers.py", line 403, in generate_response
    ).update(data).run(g.rdb_conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/remodel/monkey.py", line 18, in remodel_run
    return run(self, c, **global_optargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rethinkdb/ast.py", line 118, in run
    return c._start(self, **global_optargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 620, in _start
    return self._instance.run_query(q, global_optargs.get('noreply', False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 466, in run_query
    raise res.make_error(query)
rethinkdb.errors.ReqlServerCompileError: Expected 2 arguments but found 1 in:
r.table('quotes').filter(id='92c5160a-db57-4c3b-b2b2-2704cdcfc2b7').update(r.expr({'channelId': 'paradigmshift3d', 'quoteId': '1', 'quote': 'Testing 123', 'userId': '123', 'messageId': '456'}))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've done some googling around, but there don't seem to be any questions/issues about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by me trying to do `.filter()` with a single argument. `.filter()` is expecting a dictionary and I was simply providing `id = 92c5160a-db57-4c3b-b2b2-2704cdcfc2b7'`.

I changed the query around to

`rethink.table(model + "s").get(results["id"]).update(data).run(g.rdb_conn)`

and it's working now!